# Show running services, deployd

Tags: javascript, service, webserver, deployd

I have just installed the deployd server, and I was wondering how I can list the running services? And how can I terminate them?

Answer (score 1):

What operating system are you using?
Normally when you run "dpd" it created another process for database 'mongod' and another more for nodejs 'node'. So you have to have:

- dpd
- mongod
- node (Windows appear to me as "Evented I\O for V8 Javascript" on task manager)